# Java: Why checking for "\n" doesn't match new lines added using System.getProperty("line.separator")

Tags: java, newline

(**Updated Question**)

First, I think that `"\n"` is equivalent to `System.getProperty("line.separator")`

I wrote some methods to work with Strings some of them check for existence of new line

`if (string.charAt(i) == '\n') {//do something;}`

But I noticed that checking for `"\n"` doesn't match the new lines added by the `System.getProperty("line.separator")`

This is an **SSCCE** to demonstrate my claim!:

**Description:**
Two strings of identical text; one `alpha_String` has new lines added using `"\n"`, and the other `beta_String` has new lines added using `System.getProperty("line.separator")`

There is a method named `String removeExtraNewLines(String)` used to remove any extra new lines in a String and return it back; as its header suggests. The two strings filtered using this method.

The two buttons `buttonAlpha` and `buttonBeta` each set the text of the `JTextArea` with the filtered String

**You will notice** that the the method catch/match and remove extra new lines of  `alpha_String` but don't do the same with `beta_String`

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

public class NewLineTest extends JPanel
{

    JPanel buttonPanel;
    JPanel textAreaPanel;
    JButton buttonAlpha;
    JButton buttonBeta;
    JTextArea textArea;
    String n = "\n";
    String s = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    String alpha_String;
    String beta_String;

    public NewLineTest()
    {
        createSentencesText();
        buttonAlpha = new JButton("Alpha String");
        buttonAlpha.addActionListener(eventWatcher);

        buttonBeta = new JButton("Beta String");
        buttonBeta.addActionListener(eventWatcher);

        textArea = new JTextArea(0, 0);
        JScrollPane scrollTextArea = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        scrollTextArea.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        textArea.setEditable(false);

        buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        textAreaPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        buttonPanel.add(buttonAlpha);
        buttonPanel.add(buttonBeta);

        textAreaPanel.add(scrollTextArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, textAreaPanel, buttonPanel);
        splitPane.setDividerLocation(400);
        splitPane.setResizeWeight(.5d);
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.add(splitPane);
    }

    private void createSentencesText()
    {
        alpha_String = "A: Let’s go to the beach." + n + n
                + "B: That’s a great idea." + n
                + "A: We haven’t been in a while." + n + n
                + "B: We haven’t been in a month." + n
                + "A: The last time we went, you almost drowned." + n
                + "B: No, I didn’t." + n + n + n
                + "A: Then why did the lifeguard dive into the water?" + n
                + "B: I think he wanted to cool off." + n
                + "A: He swam right up to you." + n
                + "B: And then he turned right around." + n
                + "A: Maybe you’re right." + n
                + "B: Maybe we should get going.";


        beta_String = "A: Let’s go to the beach." + s + s
                + "B: That’s a great idea." + s
                + "A: We haven’t been in a while." + s + s
                + "B: We haven’t been in a month." + s
                + "A: The last time we went, you almost drowned." + s
                + "B: No, I didn’t." + s + s + s
                + "A: Then why did the lifeguard dive into the water?" + s
                + "B: I think he wanted to cool off." + s
                + "A: He swam right up to you." + s
                + "B: And then he turned right around." + s
                + "A: Maybe you’re right." + s
                + "B: Maybe we should get going.";
    }

    public static String removeExtraNewLines(String s)
    {
        String myNewString = s.trim();
        StringBuilder stringB = new StringBuilder();

        char previouseChar = '~';
        for (int i = 0; i < myNewString.length(); i++)
        {
            if (i > 1)
            {
                previouseChar = myNewString.charAt(i - 1);
            }
            if ((myNewString.charAt(i) == '\n') && (previouseChar == '\n'))
            {
                continue;
            }

            stringB.append(myNewString.charAt(i));
        }
        myNewString = stringB.toString();
        return myNewString;
    }
    AbstractAction eventWatcher = new AbstractAction()
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
        {
            Object source = ae.getSource();
            if (source == buttonAlpha)
            {
                String arranged_string_alpha = removeExtraNewLines(alpha_String);
                textArea.setText(arranged_string_alpha);
            }
            if (source == buttonBeta)
            {
                String arranged_string_beta = removeExtraNewLines(beta_String);
                textArea.setText(arranged_string_beta);
            }
        }
    };

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("NewLine Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(700, 300);
        frame.add(new NewLineTest(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                UIManager.put("swing.boldMetal", Boolean.FALSE);
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**So the question**: Why checking for `"\n"` doesn't match new lines added using `System.getProperty("line.separator")`?, And How to match them?

Comment: Have you verified that on your system, the System constant is in fact equal to `'\n'`?  It shouldn't take more than a simple comparison to discover, right?

Comment: First of all, which OS are you using to test this? Second, does `if (string.charAt(i) == System.getProperty("line.separator"))` not work as you expect? Third, have you tried using a debugger to examine what the value of `System.getProperty("line.separator")` actually is?

Comment: This article may interest you http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

Comment: You opened a bounty but without explaining why the most upvoted answer does not answer your question. `\n` is platform dependent, `System.getProperty("line.separator")` could be `\n` or `\r\n`.

Comment: @assylias Jon Skeet said "It's not really clear what you're trying to check at all" So I updated my question with SSCCE, I thought that the answer would be different if the question become more clearer. Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> First, I think that "\n" is equivalent to System.getProperty("line.separator") except that the later is platform independent.

No, the latter is *platform-specific*. It's the *platform-independent* way of getting your platform's line separator.

So on Windows, I'd expect `System.getProperty("line.separator")` to return "\r\n", for example.

Now as for what your `textArea` uses for a new-line - that entirely depends on what `textArea` is - and you haven't given us any information about that.

Comment: @BlackVegetable: Pedantry is an important part of being a software engineer :)

Comment: I'm going to quote you on that now!

Comment: textArea is [JTextArea](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html). According to your answer, then I must check for matching the String "\r\n", and that require checking for two consecutive charachters in the string; some code like `if((string.charAt(i) == '\r')&&((string.charAt(i++) == '\n'))`

Comment: @SalehFeek: It's not really clear what you're trying to *check* at all. But you should read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DefaultEditorKit.html

Comment: I am simply searching for **newline** `"\n"`, using -> `if(string.charAt(i) == '\n') {// do something}`; which doesn't work with newlines added using `System.getProperty("line.separator")`. That means for the smae JTextArea and the same condition `if(string.charAt(i) == '\n')`; When feeding the JTextArea with new lines using `append("\n")` they are matched by the search condition, but when I use `append(System.getProperty("line.separator"))` the search condition doesn't match this new lines. I will just avoid using `System.getProperty("line.separator")` in place of `"\n"` **Thanks** for help.

Comment: @SalehFeek: Well you could use `contains` instead... if you always use `\n` you're assuming that the line separate *always* contains `\n`.

Comment: I updated my question, I think it is clear now. **I know I am late**

Comment: @SalehFeek: The updated question contains 138 lines of code. Do you *really* thinks that's all necessary to demonstrate the problem? And at the moment you seem to be checking for two *consecutive* `\n` characters, which clearly isn't going to be the case if you're using `line.separator` and the line separator is `\r\n`, as it is on Windows.